# How to limit number of document reads from a humongous collection in firestore when some malicious user queries the data?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a firestore collection called `letters` which holds a public letter from users. In my app, I am using pagination to limit the results to 20 when they go to `public letters screen`. My concern is that this would work fine from within the app but if some malicious user query the database from let's say postman then I will be billed heavily for all those reads. I have all security rules in place like the user should be authenticated but this needs to be public collection so I can't think of anything else to restrict this. How can I restrict someone to read about 20 documents at time?

Comment: Can you be more precise about your exact requirement? I may have misunderstood your question thinking you wanted to limit **each pagination call** to 20 documents. If it is not the case, then my answer is not correct. In order to delete it you need to un accept it.

Comment: I think you get the question right and your answer also makes sense but as Doug pointed out there is no way to restrict a malicious user from doing this. One can simply execute read statements again and again with 20 as a limit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is actually no way to restrict the consumption of a collection based on direct query volume.  Renaud's answer proposes to use `request.query.limit` in security rules, but that does not stop a malicious user from simply making as many calls to the pagination API as they want.  It just forces them to provide a `limit()` on each query.  The caller can still consume the entire collection, and consume it as many times as they want.

Watch my video on the topic: https://youtu.be/9sOT5VOflvQ?t=330

If you want to enforce a hard limit on the total number of documents to read, you will need a backend to do that.  Clients can request documents from the backend up to the limit it enforces.  If the backend wants to allow pagination, it will have to somehow track the usage of the provided endpoint to prevent each caller from exhausting whatever limits or quotas you want to enforce.

Answer (score 5):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#evaluating_constraints_on_queries):

> The [`request.query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request) variable contains the [`limit`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#query), `offset`, and `orderBy`
>   properties of a query.

So you can write a rule like:

```
allow list: if request.query.limit <= 20;
```

---

Note that we use `list`, instead of `read`. The doc says:

> You can break read rules into `get` and `list` rules. Rules for `get` apply
>   to requests for single documents, and rules for `list` apply to queries
>   and requests for collections.

Comment: Actually this does not stop someone from using the pagination API to restrict reads. The caller can still just read as many batches of 20 as they want - they could easily consume the entire collection this way, and consume it as many times as they want.  All this does is require a limit on each query at or below 20.

Comment: @DougStevenson let say I'm forcing my users to signedIn to read a doc,if the query limit exceeds 20 then logging their email to a collection and updating the rules to not allow this email in upcoming days is it okay to go with?..and can i leagally take any actions on them?

Comment: There should be a simple throttle drop-down for crud whether user specific or overall after all it's too easy for Firebase to do that, as they did implemented this limits on 25$ plan.